# Textmate Find and Replace with Wildcard

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

Here's what I have in a few hundred places `[:admin, @account]`. What I want to do is remove the `[:admin, ]` so that all that's left is `@account` or whatever object I have there. Because sometimes it's `[:admin, ticket]` or `[:admin, group]`.

Is it possible with Regex to get rid of the wrapped bracket(`[]`) and `:admin,`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know, how exactly textmate is handling regex, but in Scintilla-base it would be something like

```
\[:admin,\s+([^\]]+)\]
$1
```